# Is 9585: WeDo Resource Set compatible with 45300: WeDo 2.0 Core Set?

Tags: wedo

As title, not sure if these two can work well together?

Or, should I wait for WeDo 2.0 Resource Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have understood from talking to one the people who developed WeDo version 2, it's not compatible with the old.